# Use PHP Simple HTML Dom Parser to retrieve partial id and use the result to parse another URL?

Tags: php, parsing, web-scraping, html-parsing

To learn some html, css and php I decided to create a simple page to show football scores. I'm using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser to retrieve the football scores and league table from [this BBC webpage](http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/live-scores) which was simple enough however what I would like to do now is retrieve goal scorers. Unfortunately I'm unable to parse this information as the page doesn't contain it until the fixture is clicked and the table expanded.

I noticed that each table row has the following ID:

```
<tr id="match-row-EFBO803510" class="report">
<tr id="match-row-EFBO803454" class="report">
<tr id="match-row-EFBO803452" class="report">
```

After some fiddling about I found out that the string at the end of the ID that begins with EFBO is the fixture ID. This ID can be added to the end of a url and it'll take me to a page with the information I'm looking for like so:

http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/live/partial/EFBO803510

So what I'm hoping to do is parse the site for those table rows, retrieve the fixture IDs and add each to the end of bbc.co.uk/sport/football/live/partial/ to generate a new url to parse.

Is this possible? Sorry I don't have any example code, everything I tried was throwing up php errors. This is an example of what the table looks like on the BBC website:

```
<tbody>
  <tr id="match-row-EFBO804038" class="report">
    <td class="match-score">
      <button class="hidden-text">Show stats panel</button>
      <span class="team-home">Brighton</span>
      <span class="score">5 - 0</span>
      <span class="team-away">Fulham</span>
      <span class="elapsed-time">Result</span>
    </td>
    <td class="match-link">
      <a href="/web/20160415225751/http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/35994191">Report</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="match-panel-EFBO804038" class="panel-showing live">
    <td class="details-table-container" colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row-spacer">
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Please update this thread, either accepting an answer or providing detail via comment or edit why it doesnt answer your issue

Answer (score 1):

As an example, that first link: http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/live-scores

This seems to be the site you are DOM parsing, and has `<tr id="match-row-EFBO851386" class="fixture">`, with that `EFBO851386` only repeated twice, once there and once right below.

So my recommendation is that you would want to parse for the first TR with CLASS 'fixture' and `replace("match-row-",$val)` to retrive the id.

That can be appended to url as you mentioned: `"http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/live/partial/".$id`

How you add the return of that url to your generated page depends entirely on how your adding the initial info.

I would usually use ajax and append below your initial html response, nice spinner while it does that.

But you can retrieve it before returning initial html response, really depends on how you actually parsing and how you using returned content.